# Issue in SQL Server install INI file to allow non-admin users to connect?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am trying to figure out how to edit my Configuration.ini file so that my silent install of SQL Server Express 2019 will give all local users read/write access to the database I create in the shared, named instance that I create

(This is for an EF Core 3.1 code-first application, if that matters.  I've been using it with Sqlite for a while with per-user databases.  Now I'm converting to SQL server with a shared DB)

With my current install, only my Windows Administrator can connect to the database.  I can't even browse the contents of the database as a regular user in Visual Studio SQL Server Explorer;  It sees it just fine but denies me access to its contents

So clearly I got something wrong.  I thought that setting it up to use Integrated Security would mean that all authorized Windows users could connect but nope.

Here is the connection string that everybody uses inside of my DbContext.OnConfiguring method:

```
var  cs2 =  $"Server={Environment.MachineName}\\MYCOMPANY; Database = MyCompany.Data; Trusted_Connection = True";
ob.UseSqlServer(cs2);
```

And this is my Configuration.ini file that was generated automatically the SQL Server installer when ran through it.  I used this to install the instance:

```
;SQL Server 2019 Configuration File
[OPTIONS]

IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS="True"
IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True"
ACTION="Install"
ROLE="AllFeatures_WithDefaults"
IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS="True"
SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE="True"
ENU="True"
QUIET="False"
QUIETSIMPLE="True"
; UIMODE="Normal"
UpdateEnabled="False"
USEMICROSOFTUPDATE="False"
SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE="True"
UpdateSource="MU"
FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,SNAC_SDK
HELP="False"
INDICATEPROGRESS="False"
X86="False"
INSTANCENAME="MYCOMPANY"
INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"
INSTANCEID="MYCOMPANY"
SQLTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$MYCOMPANY"
SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"
AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"
COMMFABRICPORT="0"
COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL="0"
COMMFABRICENCRYPTION="0"
MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT="0"
SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"
SQLMAXDOP="0"
ENABLERANU="True"
SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQL$GELSIGHT"
SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="True"
SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS"
SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT="1"
SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE="8"
SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH="64"
SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE="8"
SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH="64"
ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True"
TCPENABLED="0"
NPENABLED="0"
BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
SQLMAXMEMORY="2147483647"
SQLMINMEMORY="0"
```

(In case it's not obvious I've replaced my actual company name with "MYCOMPANY")

Is there some other parameter I should be using in this .INI file to give all Windows users at least connect/read/write access to the database?

I hope to avoid having all users use a dedicated account/password because I only want regular Windows admins to be able to create/migrate the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you did nothing wrong with the installation. It is by design, that you can't add users to a SQL Server platform at the installation phase, accept for the administrators. 
To add users to connect to databases, you need to make logins and after the login creation you need to create users for specific databases.

Since you just installed the SQL Server, there are no databases to give access to, except the system databases.

The best solution I can imagine is to create a "database create" trigger.

First you create a login based on a AD security group, in which all users are added that need access. 
Secondly you create a trigger on the create database event and grant rolemembership, i.e datareader to the login created on the first step.

This will ensure that all users (in the formentioned security group) get access to all created databases. I don't know if the trigger is activated when a database is created by using a backup.